# Why JasperReports Server shows empty report?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have created a sample report in Jaspersoft Studio

and I created server connection and the created report published to it. but when i open the server and check the same item which was published, it shows empty report. why it is so?

Connection to  jasper server:
[image: connection to jasper server]

Report design:
[image: report design]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
        <!-- 2016-09-23T17:10:52  -->
   <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="myCoffee" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ced95029-b569-4027-895c-af2843a4e088">
      <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/public/Samples/newwww_cofeee"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/public/Samples/newwww_cofeee_files/main_jrxml"/>
<style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
<style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
<style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from "ORDERS"]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ORDERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="SHIPNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPADDRESS" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPCITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPREGION" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="136" splitType="Stretch">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="126" uuid="ddc15723-2728-421f-b95e-2df9faf64ce1"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["coffee.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Title" x="170" y="0" width="263" height="62" uuid="1a652692-054a-40f3-ade5-68d8da36626d"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Coffee Title]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="219" y="62" width="196" height="22" uuid="88d4231e-f014-4b0d-b871-1737ba63a1ae"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Coffee SubTitle]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="172" y="94" width="383" height="42" uuid="f0bfb1ea-a85a-47cd-a1a4-43f22b45e80f"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor purus gravida arcu aliquam mattis. Donec et nulla libero, ut varius massa. Nulla sed turpis elit. Etiam aliquet mauris a ligula hendrerit in auctor leo lobortis.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <image>
            <reportElement x="433" y="-115" width="267" height="209" uuid="5d64e5b3-07bb-48ab-89dc-15c0c46bb19a"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["coffee_stain.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="15" width="555" height="1" uuid="1a61a836-d137-48b1-ad67-6ff64600bf93"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Column header" x="0" y="0" width="111" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="0ff41838-59fc-47bd-9b48-1bc622576a80"/>
            <text><![CDATA[ORDERID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Column header" x="111" y="0" width="111" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="3c5657fa-038a-4b98-a026-2f6203f5c0be"/>
            <text><![CDATA[SHIPNAME]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Column header" x="222" y="0" width="111" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="c9f171bf-1fbb-472d-a5ab-d5bd23340350"/>
            <text><![CDATA[SHIPADDRESS]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Column header" x="333" y="0" width="111" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="0907046f-988c-4903-9f92-fcc927eb8a14"/>
            <text><![CDATA[SHIPCITY]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Column header" x="444" y="0" width="111" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="d9a1b7ba-d450-4f4c-9956-ba21a8ff4066"/>
            <text><![CDATA[SHIPREGION]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15" uuid="a98495d8-3c8d-4fa0-81f5-30c3efc2f766"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" x="0" y="0" width="111" height="15" uuid="004e4afd-035d-42f8-8d5f-f2f847459fb5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" x="111" y="0" width="111" height="15" uuid="bf9e44ec-80a7-40fc-afca-60227b369850"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" x="222" y="0" width="111" height="15" uuid="60bc8d8f-c31a-491d-acaa-27c2d00a54f9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPADDRESS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" x="333" y="0" width="111" height="15" uuid="8b37170b-04ae-4269-9e01-d5e70e5c0b08"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPCITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" x="444" y="0" width="111" height="15" uuid="a0ce4789-f7ab-4eb0-94bf-35152ddbf1b5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPREGION}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1" uuid="fa45a887-615a-4d84-a2d7-8a2219671b3c"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-21" y="1" width="597" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="183682bc-d976-4756-83e0-6625a3f98ed1"/>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="533" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="0193f9b3-1559-491a-8580-b6988863b6a1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="453" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="d00b105e-494b-418b-8ac9-8b1b4824f4f0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="22" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="0616f3fe-0354-456f-8911-ec30ec51a5ae"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

Comment: How did you do it? Show your report and report deployment on server.

Comment: check, i have done the basic things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The report is empty on JasperReports Server because, most likely, you have not selected a data source when published it.

You have created and tested the report with the Sample DB that is shipped with Jaspersoft Studio. The same data, or in this case the same database table with the same structure, must be accessible to the Server, too. You specify that when you publish the report.

Luckily, there is a data source on the Server that has a similar table structure to the one in Studio. What you need to do is to republish the report in the same location and in the `Report Publishing Wizard` to select `Data Source from Repository` and either enter this path:

> /public/Samples/Data_Sources/ExmapleVDS

(the typo is intended) or manually select it by browsing through these folders:

> Public > Samples > Data Sources > ExampleVDS

in the `Repository Browser` dialog triggered by the `...` button adjacent to the input text field.

Note: The Server connection in Studio was done with the `jasperadmin` user.

Comment: it worked, i think you knew more about jasper, could you please tell, how should i use this report to embedd to my project, example Asp.net mvc

Comment: If you want to embed the JasperReports Server, you can do it with either of these: the REST API, the JavaScript API called Visualize.js or with the classical HTTP API with iframe. More info can be found in the [Embedded BI Developer Center](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedded-bi-developer-center).

Comment: I have a local db,  the connection string in my project for this db is


      <add name="CRegistryPlatformDatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\projectsv12;Initial Catalog=CRegistry.Platform.Database;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>


i want to use this DB or stored procedure in it to use for creating report in jasperstudio, so what steps i have to follow?
please provide step by step like, 
1)select project->new project
2)select template
...etc

how to configure my DB to jaspersoft.

Comment: You need to check the [Working with Database JDBC Connections](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/working-database-jdbc-connections) chapter in the Jaspersoft Studio User Guide